# Right click is not working in selenium web driver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I want to right click on a link and select the first option in context menu.

I tried with below five methods nothing works. all methods are clicking 
the link in normal way, but not happening context click.

Can somebody throw some light on this what's wrong?

I am using the environment of...selenium-3.4.0, FF 53, Windows 7

```
        package WebDriverAdvancedPrograms;


        import java.awt.AWTException;
        import java.awt.Robot;
        import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
        import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

        import org.openqa.selenium.*;
        import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
        import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action;
        import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

        public class RightClick {

            public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, AWTException {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "G:\\Selenium\\geckodriver-v0.16.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
                WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                driver.get("http://facebook.com");
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

                WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.linkText("Forgotten account?"));


    //      // Method 1 - NOT WORKING
    //      Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    //      Action mouseOverHome = builder
    //              .moveToElement(element)
    //              .contextClick(element)
    //              .sendKeys(Keys.DOWN)
    //              .sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)
    //              .build();
    //      mouseOverHome.perform();

    // Method 2 - NOT WORKING
    //      Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    //      Action mouseOverHome = builder
    //              .moveToElement(element)
    //              .contextClick(element)
    //              .sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
    //              .sendKeys(Keys.RETURN)
    //              .build();
    //      mouseOverHome.perform();

    // Method 3 - NOT WORKING
    //      Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    //      Action mouseOverHome = builder
    //              .contextClick(element)
    //              .sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
    //              .sendKeys(Keys.RETURN)
    //              .build();
    //      mouseOverHome.perform();

    // Method 4 - NOT WORKING
    //      Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    //      Action mouseOverHome = builder
    //              .contextClick(element)
    //              .sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
    //              .sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_UP)
    //              .sendKeys(Keys.RETURN)
    //              .build();
    //      mouseOverHome.perform();


    //      // Method 5 - NOT WORKING
            Actions action= new Actions(driver);
            action.contextClick(element).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).build().perform();



   // Method 6 - Partially WORKING
    Point p = element.getLocation();
    int x = p.getX();
    int y = p.getY();

    Robot r=new Robot();
    r.mouseMove(x, y);
    r.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK);
    r.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);

    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

   //Method 7 - WORKING
    Robot r=new Robot();
    r.mouseMove(1000, 145);
    r.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK);
    r.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);

    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);


        }
    }
```

Method 6 is partially working means... Context click is happening on the screen but not on element.

In Method 7, I entered manually x, y position its working...

The reason for method 6 not working is x, y getting from getLocation method is related to browser, but robot class is working related to screen..

Here my question is how to get exact location of element related to screen

Thanks
Ravi M

Comment: you can use robot class

Comment: i tried with robot class..context click is happening but not on the element. can u see the method 6 and method 7 in the above code..

Answer (score 1):

Please try,

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.ContextClick(element).Build().Perform();
```

or please try by changing RETURN to ENTER like below,

```
Actions action= new Actions(driver);
action.contextClick(element).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
```

Comment: ok. Let me create a full working example and will share it from my GitHub.

Comment: @RaviMakam I have tried the same solution on my machine and working fine. I have uploaded the sample code in GitHub. Please try to download it and check - https://github.com/vnathv/seleniummouserightclick.git . My code sample is in C# but it will be same in Java as well.

Comment: thanks for update..but i think u tried in chrome..i just want to update u 2 things. 1.context click happening in chrome ..but its not selecting option from it.... as the the forgot page is displayed in same page instead of new tab. 2. The issue i posted is for firefox. I came to know from below link that...it's an existing issue in ff. they fixed it in ff 56 version. https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/660

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
Actions right_action = new Actions(chromeDriver);  
right_action.ContextClick(element_name).SendKeys(Keys.ArrowDown).SendKeys(Keys.Enter).Build().Perform();
```

Comment: its doing normal left click not the context click as the page is loading in the same page..